# c language. SetLength, array of structs

Tags: arrays, size, pascal, ansistring

```
type
TS = record
    FN, RN: String;
end;
var 
Sy: array of TS;     
S: ^String;

...

          SetLength(Sy,2);
          begin
            Sy[0].FN:='123';
            Sy[0].RN:='bad';
            Sy[1].FN:='345';
            Sy[1].RN:='000';
          end;


...

S := @(Sy [i].FN);
```

How to imitate Pascal logic in C language?
Next code does not work:

```
typedef struct
{
       char FN[256];//char FN[] /*isn't allowed by compiler*/
       char RN[256];//char RN[] /*isn't allowed by compiler*/
} TS;
TS Sy[];
main()
{
    Sy=malloc(2*sizeof(TS));
    strcpy(Sy[1].FN,"1234");
}
```

QUESTION 1

I get compiler error `error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value`. What should I do to imitate Pascal logic in case of SetLength?

QUESTION 2

How to specify a string of unknown size (Ansistrings is Pascal). When I set `char FN[];`  I get error `error C2229: struct '<unnamed-tag>' has an illegal zero-sized array` . What should I do to imitate Pascal logic in case of Ansistring?

Comment: Must it be plain C, and not e.g. C++ ? C++ at least has std::string.

Comment: It must be ANSI C. **Not C++.**

Comment: As I can see in debugger, Pascal's SetLength(Sy,2) will allocate memory of 6 dwords:01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00. 1st dword is always $00000001 (little-Endian order)(I don't know what purpose it is for). 2nd dword is number of elements decreased by 1. 3rd is Sy[0].FN address (pointer on string, which will be pushed in FN). 4th is Sy[0].RN address. 5th is Sy[1].FN address. 6th is Sy[1].RN address.

And Pascal's Length(Sy) will just recieve address of allocated 6 dwords as parameter, increase it by 4 (so it's 2nd dword), extract value, increase it by 1.

Comment: So to imitate Pascal logic I must push length of array to element [-1] (in dword notation).

Comment: It can be done by next C-language code : Sy=calloc(sizeof(TS) * nuu + sizeof(unsigned long int),1); Sy=&((unsigned long int*)Sy)[1]; ((unsigned long int*)Sy)[-1] = nuu;

Comment: testnamec04: The first dword is a reference count. Note that strings are also such types. (the returned pointers doesn't point to the start of the allocation, the allocation is larger than the character data; there is data prefixed, refcount,and length, as well as codepage in newer versions), and have copy on write semantics. Naievely messing with them in C will only get you a bunch of GPFs. Better write some pascal code that acts as accessors that works with C types (char * + length), and call that from C. That also abstracts you version wise from differences between object pascal verrsions

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
malloc() returns a void pointer (void*), so I think Sy would need to be a pointer type. The most direct way would be changing `TS Sy[]` to `TS *Sy`. Then when using malloc you will need to cast the pointer to a TS pointer, like so:
Sy = (TS*)malloc(2*sizeof(TS));

Question 2:
As far as I'm aware, the only suitable type that would work would be a c-string. In which case the solution is similar to that in question one, change `FN[]` and `RN[]` to `*FN` and `*RN`. I'm not very experienced with C however, and that may not be the most efficient way to handle things, especially since then I believe the struct will not take up a contiguous memory space. Another problem with this is you will still need to specify the size of the c-string at some point, but you will be able to do it dynamically, rather than at compile time.

(Edit) As a side note, you should also use free() to free the memory allocated by malloc when you're done with it.

Comment: As I can see in OllyDBG, Visual Studio generates identical code in both cases `Sy = (TS*)malloc(2*sizeof(TS));` and `Sy = malloc(2*sizeof(TS));`. So type cast is not needed.